# Munin stopped working after rebooting the server

Tags: linux, debian, munin

Munin stopped working after rebooting the server. When I try to run, it gives:

```
Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
munin-node.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Failed to start Munin Node.
```

And this:

```
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Пн 2017-05-15 14:35:01 MSK; 4min 27s ago
```

What is this and how can I solve this problem?

Logs:

```
May 15 14:32:58 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:32:59 atrone systemd[1]: munin-node.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
May 15 14:32:59 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:32:59 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:32:59 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:32:59 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:33:00 atrone systemd[1]: munin-node.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
May 15 14:33:00 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:33:00 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:34:54 atrone systemd[1]: munin-node.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
May 15 14:34:54 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:34:54 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:34:57 atrone systemd[1]: munin-node.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
May 15 14:34:57 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:34:57 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:34:59 atrone systemd[1]: munin-node.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
May 15 14:34:59 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:34:59 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:35:00 atrone systemd[1]: munin-node.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
May 15 14:35:00 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:35:00 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:35:01 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:35:01 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
May 15 14:35:01 atrone systemd[1]: munin-node.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
May 15 14:35:01 atrone systemd[1]: Failed to start Munin Node.
May 15 14:35:01 atrone systemd[1]: Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: Do you have something in the logs ?

Comment: @Dom I added logs to my question

Comment: And the munin logs ?

Comment: And check the /var/run/munin/ dir : it should be owned by "munin" user

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem an hour ago on an Debian based system. For me reinstalling the `munin-node` package fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall munin-node
```

If this doesn't help, you should check your logs in `/var/log/munin/`. You can start with `/var/log/munin/munin-node.log`